# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe') of subscribe inside ngOnInit with unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine

Currently facing a unit test errror:

```
AppComponent > should call app
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
```

Inside my ngOnInit I have:

```
this.eventsService.currentEvents.subscribe(events => {
  this.events = events;
  return this.processEvents(this.events);
});
```

The test where it fails is here (where ngOnInit is called):

```
  it(`should call app`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    app.ngOnInit();
  });
```

And my events service is:

```
export class EventsService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private store: Store<AppState>) {}
  
  private eventsSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  currentEvents: Observable<any> = this.eventsSource .asObservable();
  
  getEvents(events: []) {
   this.eventsSource.next(events);
  }
}
```

The app.component.spec has this set up as well:

```
  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: EventsService , useValue: {
          getEvents: () => of([]),
          processEvents: () => of([])
        }},
        provideMockStore({}),
        { provide: Angulartics2, useValue: {} },
        { provide: Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics, useValue: { startTracking: () => {}} },
        { provide: WindowRef }
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    eventService = TestBed.inject(EventsService);
    (<any>window).ga = jasmine.createSpy('ga');
  });
```

Comment: From what you've provided, it sounds like you haven't set up a mock service to be injected since `AppComponent` requires `EventsService`. If you do have this set up, might be worth posting how you've done that too.

Comment: Thanks @miqh, i've edited to show the EventsService added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `EventService` provider, add the service property `currentEvents` too.

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: EventsService, useValue: {
      getEvents: () => of([]),
      processEvents: () => of([]),
      currentEvents: of('events')
    }
  },
]
```